# Bash script not understood by Ubuntu Bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am new to Bash Script.  I run the following simple script in Ubuntu like this:

```
sudo bash -x Script.sh
```

Output:

```
+ $'\r'
: command not found
+ $'\r'
: command not found
+ $'\r'
: command not found
+ adminEmail=$'info@domain.com\r'
+ $'\r'
: command not found
' echo 'database name:
database name:
+ read $'dbname\r'
```

The actual script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Installation script for latest Wordpress website on Ubuntu
# 
# Kave
# December 27, 2011


adminEmail="info@domain.com"

echo "database name:"
read dbname
```

What are all these `'\r'` error messages coming up? Even the comments seem not to be understood...

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with the line endings, but I don't know how to fix this...

Comment: It works for me... Arch Linux i686

Comment: From the command line do `dos2unix scriptname scriptname`. `\r` are carriage returns, did you create the file on a windows machine and sent it to linux?

Comment: yes, Jaypal, thats what I did.

Comment: Just do `dos2unix scriptname` and execute your script.

Comment: I didnt have doc2unix and went rather with the Vi trick. Its good to know about that command though. Thanks

Comment: That's fine. I updated the answer to include how can you can download the tool `dos2unix`. Good luck :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You downloaded the file via a Windows machine, and you have CRLF line endings (that's `\r\n` in C and related languages).

Remove the DOS line endings.  For example, edit the file in `vim` and change the format with `:set fileformat=unix` (plus <kbd>Return</kbd>) and then write the file back out.  Alternative techniques could use the `tr` command, or `dos2unix` or `dtou`, depending on what's available.

Answer (score 12):

Simply do

```
dos2unix scriptname
```

and execute your script.

If you don't have the tool you can do the following to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

**OR**

Do the following command line hacks to convert the file.

```
tr -d '\015' < scriptname > scriptname.new
```

**OR**

```
sed -i 's/\x0D$//' scriptname
```

Answer (score 1):

Cut and paste your code from this page into an editor on your Ubuntu, so you'll get your line-endings fixed (`\r\n` on windows vs `\n` on Linux for instance)

If you save it as a new file I'm sure it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there are some extraneous non-printable characters in the file.
Open the file in Vi/Vim:
press `[ESC]` to get into command mode
then type `:set list`

Comment: And once you've got the characters listed, how would you go about removing them?  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your answer is very much on the right lines, but it isn't yet complete.